# how do you install ricochet in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

how do you install [ricochet](https://ricochet.im/) in ubuntu 14.04 64bit?

Comment: You'll have to download the `x86_64` version of the `.tar.bz2` file and unzip that and play around with it to get it to work.  There's likely an `INSTALL` file inside that folder that contains instructions.

Comment: please follow my answer...

Answer (score 5):

1.Download the file from [official site](https://ricochet.im/).

If you have any confusion download from [github.com/ricochet](https://github.com/ricochet-im/ricochet/releases)

[image: Imgur]

2.Change to downloaded folder and Extract the files of **tar.bz2**:

```
 cd ~/Downloads
 tar xvjf ricochet-1.1.1-static-x86_64.tar.bz2
```

3.To read user manual:

```
 xdg-open README
```

From README file,it is clear that no need to configure,so directly run:

```
./ricochet
```

[image: Imgur]

[image: Imgur]

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)! **;-)**